# How to parse datetime without error

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, ado.net

I'd like to retrieve some data from a database. However, I get an error when trying to parse the `DateTime`

```
public static List<purchinvoice> retrieve_purchinvoice()
{
     List<purchinvoice> pilist = new List<purchinvoice>();
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBconnection.connectstr);
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("retrieve_purch_invoice", con);
     com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     SqlDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();
     if (r.HasRows)
     {
         while (r.Read())
         {
             purchinvoice pi = new purchinvoice();
             pi.purch_serial_number = r[0].ToString();
             pi.p_date = DateTime.Parse(r[1].ToString());
             pi.sup_name = r[2].ToString();
             pilist.Add(pi);
         }
     }
     return pilist;
}
```

and the code behind is:

```
List<purchinvoice> pil = purchinvoice.retrieve_purchinvoice();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Serial Number");
dt.Columns.Add("Date");
dt.Columns.Add("Supplier Name");

foreach (purchinvoice pi in pil)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = pi.purch_serial_number;
    dr[1] = string.Format("{0:D}", pi.p_date);
    dr[2] = pi.sup_name;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}

GridView_purchinvoice.DataSource = new DataView(dt);
GridView_purchinvoice.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert datetime in `String` format. I highly recommend to use `DateTime` datatype in SQL. The database natively support it and you can read without `Parse` or `ToString`.

Or, if the database is not under your control, try to do as below.

**Insert to database as below**

```
dr[1] = pi.p_date.ToString("o"); // ISO 8601 format
```

**Read from database as below**

```
pi.p_date = DateTime.Parse(r[1].ToString());
```

Note that you may have risk to handle timezone offset. If it is your case, please check UTC conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
   DateTime.TryParse(r[1].ToString(), out pi.p_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse the `DateTime` string without any exception/error, you should check whether the string can be parsed into `DateTime` object or not. So to do this, you can use [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
DateTime myDateTime;
if(DateTime.TryParse(r[1].ToString(), out myDateTime))
{
   pi.p_date = myDateTime
}
```

If your string is in specific format of datetime and you want to parse it to the `DateTime` object then you can use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) in which you can specify the string format by which you want to parse.